# Bulk Upload from Fileshare to SP 2013 with Metadata

Tags: file-upload, file-metadata

I have found a powershell script to upload multiple files to a document library in SharePoint 2010 however I am using the 2013 version. Would this still work?

Link to script : http://www.spfileupload.codeplex.com/

This is a great script to add the files and fill in the columns of the document library with extra metadata i provide in a XML file.
I hope there are other ways to do this in SP2013

Thanks!

Kevin

Answer (score 3):

You still can't do bulk file uploading with metadata (both simple and managed) in SharePoint 2013.

Also, I don't see any reason why [SPFileUpload script](http://spfileupload.codeplex.com/) wouldn't work in SP2013.